# spring-boot 2.0.6 velocity view issue with resource-loader-path property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, velocity

When vm file is located in `classpath:/templates/hello.vm`, everything works fine on spring-boot-1.5.x.

When the vm file is located `classpath:/templates/hello.vm` or moved to the `classpath:/template/WEB-INF/view/hellow.vm` and renewing the `application.yml` as following, it doesn't work anymore on spring-boot-2.0.6-RELEASE.

**My application.yml:**

```
spring:
    velocity:
    enabled: true
    view-names: 
    resource-loader-path: classpath:/templates/WEB-INF/view/         
    expose-request-attributes: true
```

**My controller:**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String index(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", "SpringBlog from Millky");
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

**My template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Hello Millky</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Hello! ${name}</h2>
    <div>Velocity version</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works on spring-boot-1.5.x but doesn't work on spring-boot-2.0-6-RELEASE.

Answer (score 2):

Spring boot has deprecated the velocity template support since `v1.4 version`.

> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.velocity.VelocityAutoConfigurationDeprecated.  as of 1.4 following the deprecation of Velocity support
>   in Spring Framework 4.3

The following class is not part of Spring boot autoconfigure jar version 2.x (i.e. Spring boot v 2.x) any more. So, it doesn't work on Spring boot version 2.

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.velocity.VelocityAutoConfiguration
```

Also, as per my understanding, if you are using the dependencies correctly, it shouldn't work on 1.5.x version as well.

Comment: I see, then did you mean that I cannot use velocity view any mode in spring-boot-2.0?

Comment: Yes, auto configuration doesn't work. You need to configure manually if you need to use velocity. Spring deprecated velocity because it is difficult for templates in their opinion when compared to other available options.

Comment: Kindly accept the answer so that it will be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

spring-boot-2.0 don’t support velocity view any more like the above answer.

Instead of velocity using Freemaker

no settings are needed in application.yml

```
    [pom.xml] - add freemaker dependency
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    [Controller]
    @CrossOrigin
    @SkipSessionCheck
    @GetMapping(baseUri+"/buy/pg/test")
    public ModelAndView impViewTest() throws ResultCodeException {
        try {

            System.out.println("/buy/pg/test") ;
            logger.debug("/buy/pg/test") ;
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

            model.addObject("errorTitle", "Error") ;
            model.addObject("errorMessage", "success : No Error !!!") ;
            model.setViewName("paygate/error");
            return model ;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(AppUtil.excetionToString(e)) ;
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

            model.addObject("errorTitle", "Error") ;
            model.addObject("errorMessage", e.getMessage()) ;
            model.setViewName("paygate/error");
            return model ;
        }
    }

    [error.ftl] - view file extension is ftl
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="ko">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>error</title>
     </head>
    <body>
    <h1>${errorTitle}</h1>
    <p>${errorMessage}</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: But, I had a problem yet.  my Freemaker view print MVC model value twice like ErrorError.